# Sending Push Notification to Multiple Selected Devices with FCM

Tags: php, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send multiple Selected Devices via FCM,
Below are my codes, currently I could only send to one device.

```
public function send_fcm()
    {
        $project="some-project";
        require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
        $client = new Google\Client();
        $client->setAuthConfig('../menicon_images/some-project-firebase-adminsdk-kgpuf-afs957ea.json');
        $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging');
        $result = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();
        $accessToken=$result["access_token"];

        $fcmUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/'.$project.'/messages:send';

        $notification = [
            'title' =>"Some title",
            'body' => "SOme message",
        ];

        $fcmNotification =[
                'message' => [
                    'token' => "some-token-device",
                    'notification' => $notification,
                ],
            ];

        $headers = [
            'Authorization: Bearer '.$accessToken,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ];       

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$fcmUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fcmNotification));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

I had seen the code that is able to send to all devices, but I need to send to specific devices not device.
I looking for a way to send an array of tokens to FCM.

Comment: If I am not wrong, FCM uses topic to specify which devices can receive notifications. So your devices need some way (maybe api or curl) to join such topic

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/send-multiple

Answer (score 1):

From the Firebase documentation on [sending messages to multiple devices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices)

> Important: The send methods described in this section were deprecated on June 21, 2023, and will be removed in June 2024. For protocol, instead use the standard [HTTP v1 API send method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send), implementing your own batch send by iterating through the list of recipients and sending to each recipient's token. For Admin SDK methods, make sure to update to the next major version. See the Firebase [FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#fcm-depr-features) for more information.

And from that FAQ, this is the required action:

> Migrate to the standard [HTTP v1 API send method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-specific-devices), which supports HTTP/2 for multiplexing.

So you'll have to call the regular send method for each recipient, and ensure HTTP/2 multiplexing to optimize resource usage across those calls.

Alternatively, you can [use a topic to reach multiple recipients with one API call](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-topics) in a publish/subscribe pattern - although that is not a direct replacement.

Comment: Thanks I managed to solve it, 
1. I need to create a group with a list of device tokens, and I get my notification key
2. Now I could send notification by the notification key and those devices will get it.

Comment: I there an API documentation? Now I stuck at adding a badge number, previous API has a parameter name 'badge' now is no longer around.

Comment: I'd recommend against using device groups these days, and instead use the approach from the documentation I highlighted in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

As i understood your question you want to send notification to multiple devices. To send FCM messages to multiple devices using specific tokens, you need to modify the structure of your `$fcmNotification` array. Instead of having a single `message` key with a single token, you can create an array of messages, each with its own token. Here's an example of how you can modify your code:

```php
public function send_fcm()
{
    $project = "some-project";
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $client = new Google\Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('../menicon_images/some-project-firebase-adminsdk-kgpuf-afs957ea.json');
    $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging');
    $result = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();
    $accessToken = $result["access_token"];

    $fcmUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/' . $project . '/messages:send';

    $notification = [
        'title' => "Some title",
        'body' => "SOme message",
    ];

    $deviceTokens = ["some-token-device1", "some-token-device2", "some-token-device3"]; // Add your device tokens to this array

    $fcmNotifications = [];

    foreach ($deviceTokens as $token) {
        $fcmNotifications[] = [
            'message' => [
                'token' => $token,
                'notification' => $notification,
            ],
        ];
    }

    $headers = [
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fcmUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fcmNotifications));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

In this example, the `$deviceTokens` array contains the FCM tokens of the devices you want to send messages to. The `foreach` loop then constructs an array of `$fcmNotifications`, each with its own token. This array is then sent to FCM using the `curl` request.

Make sure to replace `"some-token-device1"`, `"some-token-device2"`, etc., with the actual FCM tokens of the devices you want to target.

Comment: Had tried it, and get error from FCM. Will need to group the recipients